# program in java that Reads data row by row and displays the data in tabular form along with the row totals, column totals and grand total

Tags: java, arrays, design-patterns, multidimensional-array

Question: Write a program that queries a user for the number of rows and columns representing students and their marks. 
Reads data row by row and displays the data in tabular form along with the row totals, column totals and grand total.

hint

[image: hint]

```
import java.io.*;
class tabular {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows");
        int row = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns");
        int col = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int A[] [] = new int[10][10];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers below: ");
        for(int r=0; r<row; r++) {
            for(int c=0; c<col; c++) {
                System.out.print("INPUT ["+ r +"] ["+ c +"] = ");
                A[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe matrix generated is: ");

        //Calculating the sum of rows
        int r;
        int c;
        for(r=0; r<row; r++) {
            int tempRow = 0;
            for(c=0; c<col; c++) {
                tempRow += A[r][c];
            }
            A[r][c] = tempRow;
        }
        //Calculating sum of the column
        for(c=0; c<col; c++) {
             int tempCol= 0;
            for(r=0; r<row; r++) {
                tempCol += A[r][c];
            }
            A[r][c] = tempCol;
        }

        //Display the tabular layout
        for(r=0; r<=row; r++) {
            for(c=0; c<=col; c++) {
                System.out.print( A[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}

OUTPUT
--------
Enter the number of rows
2
Enter the number of columns
3
Enter the numbers below:
INPUT [0] [0] = 1
INPUT [0] [1] = 2
INPUT [0] [2] = 3
INPUT [1] [0] = 4
INPUT [1] [1] = 5
INPUT [1] [2] = 6

The matrix generated is:
1 2 3 6
4 5 6 15
5 7 9 0
```

**At the end, 0 is displayed instead of the addition result of the column or rows which is 21. Where did I go wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of rows are created as another column. When you are calculating sum of columns you are missing added column, so final total was not displaying.
use c < col+1 instead of c < col in the for loop.
it should solve the problem.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks, why didn't I think of that before. @anilkumar